# Topicality of NATO phonetic alphabet

Tags: discussion, scope

From our recent questions:

[What is the meaning of "Bravo"?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/34282/58)

I'm not sure whether to consider this question on topic, because it concerns astronauts using domain-specific terminology (it happens that the domain it is specific to is not unique to space exploration, but it is domain-specific nevertheless), or whether to consider this off topic because the NATO phonetic alphabet is not really a space topic.

I don't have a preference of which way we rule it, but if we keep it as on topic, I would like to close all other questions about the meaning of NATO phonetic alphabet terminology as duplicates of this question in the future.

What do you think?

Comment: Possible confusion when it comes to "what does delta mean"

Comment: @JCRM We won't have that question if we don't allow any further questions about individual letters, as I and Russell have suggested.

Comment: my point being that delta often doesn't mean a letter

Comment: @JCRM Yes, I understood that, but what I'm saying is that we won't have that question about the NATO phonetic delta, so there won't be any ambiguity.

Comment: @JCRM If someone does ask that question about the NATO phonetic delta, we can edit the title before we close it as duplicate.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't feel too strongly about it, but I lean towards saying it's on-topic; we have a few "what does this terminology used by astronauts mean" questions, and just because the answer applies to aviation as well as astronautics doesn't make it off-topic. I agree that we don't need one Q/A per NATO phonetic alphabet codeword. :)

Comment: Sounds good to me.

Answer (score 3):

Agreed, it's something we had to learn in shuttle Mission Operations, and it's somewhere in most JSC 'goody books' and introductory training materials.

[image]

Comment: Interesting that they included the temperature conversion for Rankines.  Did you ever see it used?

Comment: @DrSheldon It wasn't rare. Here's a hardcopy of a display from the simulator showing some engine temperatures in deg R. https://imgur.com/a/SwPmyBs